# Cant make $http work, not showing response

Tags: angularjs

I can´t make $http work and also, I can´t find WHAT is the problem. The "request" is working (200) but I do not know WHY I can´t show the results. I´m really stuck.

Here is the code.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="app1" ng-controller="mcontrol as ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="x in ctrl.list">
<span ng-bind="x.name"></span>
</div>
</div>

<script src="angular.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module("app1", [])
.controller("mcontrol", ["$http", function($http)
{
    $http.get("myfile.php").then(function(response)
    {
        this.list = response.data;
    },
    function(errorresponse)
    {
        console.error("Error");
    });
}]);

</script>
```

**myfile.php**

```
[
{name: "Juan"},
{name: "Carlos"},
{name: "Ramiro"}
]
```

**Console**

```
GET 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 31ms]
GET 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/angular.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 12ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/myfile.php [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 14ms]
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: your `php` file should actually be a `.json` file.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Or you need to "echo" the data in your PHP file. Either way, you need that file to deliver the data back to whatever calls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its kind of context scoping related issue, `this` you are using inside `$http` is not the `this` of the controller function.

I'd say that create a variable & assign this into it, inside your controller function itself like `var vm = this`.

**Code**

```
angular.module("app1", [])
.controller("mcontrol", ["$http", function($http) {
    var vm = this;
    $http.get("myfile.php")
     .then(function(response) {
        vm.list = response.data;
     },
     function(errorresponse) {
        console.error("Error");
    });
}]);
```

Comment: You made MY DAY! Thanksssss! :D

Comment: @Peter Glad to help you.. Thanks :)